# Google Maps JavaScript API - how to style businesses?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to style a Google Maps map, and by request I need to style the colors of businesses within a certain area.

According to the [Maps JS docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference), I should be able to do the following:

```js
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#ff0000" }
    ]
  }
]
```

But nothing happens. However, I can easily style the labels, roads, etc.

Does any of you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your styles with [Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com).

For instance, applying the following style

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ff0000"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

to

[image]

results in

[image]

Comment: Oh hey, I didn't know that link existed. Thanks, that'll be bookmarked in a jiffy.

I guess I need something extra plugged into the Maps JS, as I want to style different types of stores in an indoor-ish map. And the `poi.business` doesn't cover that, apparently.